# How can I prevent a sinon spy from calling the method being spied on?

Tags: javascript, sinon

I wrote a simple test where I spy on $.ajax using Sinon.js. However, I see "WARN [web-server]: 404: /people" in my terminal. Why is it calling $.ajax when it is being spied on?

```
var people = {
    findAll: function() {
        return $.ajax({ url: '/people' })
    }
};
var spy = sinon.spy($, 'ajax');
people.findAll();
$.ajax.restore();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a `sinon.stub` instead. Stubs can also be programmed to behave in a specific way. For example `$.ajax.yields('foo')` invokes a given callback.